# Fluid Momentum Equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acceleration, flow, navier-stokes

I have a equation regarding the fluid equation of momentum. What exactly is being accelerated/acted on?   My understanding is this:

The momentum is equation (at least in my textbook) is derived by applying Newton’s 2nd law to an arbitrarily located, infinitesimally small, control volume (C.V) in the flow.

This infinitesimal C.V, at any point in time, will have an infinitesimal fluid element passing through it. Thus, the forces that act on the C.V at any point in time, are accelerating the fluid element that happens to be passing through at that time.

Thus, the momentum equation is stating that the acceleration of any fluid element, at any point in space and time is equal to the forces acting on the C.V that the fluid element occupies at that point in space and time.

Do I have the right idea here?

Comment: The forces are acting on the packet of fluid within the control volume, not the control volume.